# RecyclerViewActions returns NoMatchingViewException in Espresso Android Testing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

I'm using this line of code to perform a click on `RecyclerView`'s list at `position` 0.

```
onView(withId(R.id.rv)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
```

But it's not working and returns `NoMatchingViewException`.

But, when I perform a click operation on `TextView` (which is inside the `RecyclerView` layout), it's working and testing is passing, as shown in the line of code below,

```
    onView(allOf(result(withId(R.id.tv), 0), isDisplayed())).perform(click());
```

Am I using the `RecyclerViewActions` correctly, and how do I resolve the issue?

Comment: This onView(withId(R.id.rv).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click())); can't compile as there's a missing closing bracket before .perform.

Comment: It was a typo in question, but when I wrote code it was correct.

Comment: What happens if you run this onView(withId(R.id.rv)).check(matches(isDisplayed())) ?

Comment: Its passing the check. Moreover, when it shows that NoMatchingViewException, I can easily find my RecyclerView inside my View Hierarchy which is shown in the Run Console.

Comment: could you add a SystemClock.sleep(1000) before the click? Just to check if it's a timing issue.

Comment: I tried, it's not a timing issue.

Comment: Could you post your full code and I'll try to reproduce it.